# Highcharts shared tooltip requires different valueSuffix and varying decimals

Tags: highcharts

I have a Highchart Graph that plots Temperature, Wind, Pressure and Rainfall.

It can be seen here http://www.dmjsystems.co.uk/weather/forecast.php

I am using a shared Tooltip with the added complication that the Max Rain is a total of the min and the max in the stacked column for rain. Currently the code ignores my series based suffix and I have not been able to get individual decimals to work (i.e.they all show 3 decimal places).

Each of the Items has a different suffix (Temp = (Degree sign)C, Wind = mph, Pressure = mb and Rain = in) and different numbers of decimal places (Wind = none, Temp = 1, Pressure = 1 and Rain = 3).

I am currently using a general Tooltip coded as follows :

```
    tooltip: { shared : true,
            formatter: function() {
            return '<span style="color:#039;font-weight:bold">' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%A' + ', ' + '%b %d' + ', ' + '%H' + ':' + '00',this.x) + '</span><br/>' +
                       this.points.map(function(point, idx) {
                           return '<span style="color:' + point.series.color + '">' + point.series.name +
                                  '</span>: <span style="color:#669;font-weight:bold">' +
                                  Highcharts.numberFormat((idx == 0) ? point.total : point.y,3) +
                                  '</span>';
                       }).join('<br/>');
            }
    },
```

but I think I need to move this (apart from shared : true) to series based tooltips that use pointFormat (especially tooltip.ySuffix which I think will let me specify the suffix correctly) and valueDecimals to set the decimal point for each series, but I cannot find any examples of code to use these functions.

Also as soon as I move away from the general tooltip I cannot get the totalling to work for the stacked column.

If anyone could point me in right direction I would appreciate it.

Comment: Have exactly same requirements. By overriding the formatter at the shared tooltip level, I was unable to get access to individual series level tooltip overrides for say valueSuffix or valueDecimals. Find any solution this?

Answer (score 7):

You can simple add a tooltip options to each serie.
You can see the options on the following [link](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.tooltip).
This way you don't have to format each serie's point.

```
series: [{
    name: 'USD',
    data: yourData,
    tooltip: {
        ySuffix: ' USD',
        yDecimals: 4
    }
}, {
    name: 'EUR',
    data: yourData,
    tooltip: {
        yPrefix: 'EUR ',
        yDecimals: 1
    }
}]
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/bru6M/)

*Reference*:

- [Highcharts tooltip](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.tooltip)

Comment: Thak you, but how do I total the stacked bar in this case?

Comment: Like the OP, I was hoping to use a mixed combination of shared tooltip for the formatter etc, with the ability to then override some settings at the individual series level where they are custom. Eg. valueSuffix, valuePrefix, valueDecimals etc.

Answer (score 2):

it is possible to use a shared tooltip and set prefixes, suffixes etc. You just have to think about the wording. Rather than use yprefix etc you use valuePrefix

You set it for each series in the data

```
series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
        type: 'column'

    }, {
        data: [216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5],
        tooltip: {
    valuePrefix: ' USD'
}}],
```

You can see a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/noelnoegdip/8x4HM/) here showing it

Comment: This doesn't appear to work with the shared tooltip is used and a formatter has been defined on the shared level tooltip setting. Your fiddle example was helpful in so far as there does appear to be some limited support for shared with individual series overrides. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify a custom formatter for the chart's tooltip, and then a value suffix and any other options in the series tooltip, then reference those options in the chart's tooltip formatter function. E.g.:

```html
$('XXXX').highcharts({
 ...
 tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                    var text = "";
                    $.each(this.points, function(index) {
                        text += '<br/><b>' + this.series.name + ":</b> "+ this.y+" "+this.series.tooltipOptions.valueSuffix;
                    });
                    return text;
                },
                shared: true
            },
 ...
});

...

chart.addSeries({
            ...
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' '+seriesUnit,
                valueDecimals:2
            },
            ...
        });
```